# How to decide where is the line between StackOverflow and ServerFault

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, down-votes

My question in Serverfault just got down-voted and closed: https://serverfault.com/questions/455030/tunneling-http-requests-in-windows-server-2012

My problem is right at the line between code and configuration, I posted my question (designed for a programmer) in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709484/restsharp-tunneling-in-windows-server-2012, and because I considered that it may involve configuration, I also created my question (in serverfault) , I DO NOT consider that I did wrong by posting in both websites, in fact, I could get different answers from Programmers and System Administrators, the answer from both could help me solve my problem, maybe only one of them knows all the complete answer. Furthermore, the comments posted by the people who closed it makes me think they do not handle the topic they just close.

I would like to know If I did wrong here and how to avoid it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I closed your question as off-topic for one simple reason: **You posted essentially the same question on Stack Overflow and Server Fault.**

All you did for your question here was trim the code out (and included a link back to your Stack Overflow question in its place) - that doesn't substantially change what you're asking, and as others have pointed out crossposting is verboten on Stack Exchange sites (you can always ask the crew in the SF chatroom to take a look at a Stack Overflow question if you think it could benefit from a sysadmin perspective).

That is the be-all and end-all of my moderation decision on this question - if we had a "was crossposted" close reason I would have used that instead of off-topic, but our choices are limited so I went with what fit best.

---

As a personal thing, I try to offer guidance whenever I close a question (particularly if I can do so with a link-and-run comment that aims the asker at something that might be helpful).

The link I left you in my comment is because based on my (admittedly quick) evaluation your question indicates that you probably have an SSL request, and don't realize it because of the screwy way Fiddler treats HTTPS (or HTTP w/ negotiated TLS) traffic.

If you read the link I provided you'll see that when Fiddler says "Protocol: HTTP" and "Host:Tunnel To" it is typically indicating that the traffic is HTTPS. That link also points you to a setting in Fiddler that has it operate as a man-in-the-middle and decrypt traffic so it can show the Host: header contents.

It is, of course, equally possible that's *not* what's going on in your case, or not what you were originally asking, but delving into what your system is doing and why is really more of a programming matter anyway, and better left for the Stack Overflow folks.

Just my $3.50 (ain't inflation the best?)

Comment: Fair enough, discussion is what moves society forward, indeed you are right, either I should have put more effort on the way I presented my question in ServerFault or just not posting anything at all, I do think though, that further revisions should be made on "cross-posting". In real life, I've had to discuss issues with programmers and system administrators at the same time, so just the fact that a question is posted in SO shouldn't automatically discouraged the same topic in SF. As you said, just my $ 3.50, indeed are granted.

Comment: @JorgeAlvarado The "no cross-posting" thing has come up from time to time on mSO ([this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) seems to be the canonical Q&A for it).  It's not always a clear-cut ***NO*** (for example if you asked on SO and the answers lead you to a related question on topic for SF, that's generally considered fine), but identical or mostly-identical questions are discouraged. There's definitely a place for cross-talk though - Using chat (or even Meta) to facilitate that seems reasonable to me but I'm open to other ideas too.

Comment: understood, thanks for the help anyway, this is the first "controversy" I got into and I'm satisfied with the output, you never stop learning. I will probably delete my account in SF though, I'm not so much into the "Infrastructure" realm anyway :P

Comment: @JorgeAlvarado Oh boy you think THIS is controversy? You should see the discussion about whether cPanel questions are "professional sysadmin" related or not ([some idiot went and defended them and we've been regretting the aftermath ever since](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3428/32986))

Comment: hahahaha, man, looks like ServerFault is a whole new twilight zone (no pun intended) :D , you got some serious issues around here, though we in SO we have [our issues too] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)

Answer (score 5):

I've read your question several times and don't understand what it is you're asking, to be honest I think it's NARQ. The technologies you are using are not those that we would typically use to administer a system. If you look at [.net](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/.net) we have 59 people following it and 268 questions compared to stackoverflow which has 12k followers and 19k questions.

Similarly [fiddler](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fiddler), [rest](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rest) [json](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/json)

The answer to your question may well be a server configuration tweak but you don't provide anywhere near enough information in a language that we can understand to help you.

Comment: ok I see, probably my mistake, but honestly I do not know how to rephrase my question any more simple. Usually you as System Administrator use WireShark or similar to monitor the whole traffic of your network card, I as programmer use Fiddler, to monitor the HTTP protocol only, If I make a simple HTTP request, then all Fiddler tells me is that is being tunneled to that microsoft address that should be something pretty common for administrators that handle windows server, what do you think?

Comment: @lain and the other thing is that the moderators did wrong by closing without making sure they understand the topic, that definetely pushed a button on me.

Comment: sorry for the spam, @lain but if serverfault do not support the tag .net, why is even there anyway?

Comment: Wireshark can filter traffic, there's quite a few ways to capture just HTTP traffic too. The request to iecvlist.microsoft.com is checking if your destination site is on the Compatibility View list, it's not actually tunneling your request. This seems solidly a .NET programming issue, which is well into [SO] and Off-Topic on [SF]. Cross posting is against the rules; I appreciate that you want multiple points of view, but don't do it, ever. If you post a Q on one site and don't get an Answer, Flag it for Migration and we'll move it. Voretaq was correct that's it off-topic, and he stated as much

Comment: @ChrisS THANK YOU!!! that is exactly the kind of answer I was expecting, your answer is completely different of Voretaq, that is the difference when you know what you are talking about, what you just told me makes much more sense now, you see, if you are taling about Compatibility View that is Configuration .. not code, anyway, I saw that you answered in stackoverflow, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Your original question was about the difference you see when you do the same thing with and without ".net" involved. How is that a server issue? You have already stated that a raw request gives the correct result, so clearly everything is fine on the server end. Your problem is very obviously with your code, which makes it a coding question, which belongs on SO.

Comment: I do not share your opinion @John, because I could have used the REST Client of Sharepoint (which is a packaged software) and call the same REST API on ad different port than 80, and have the same results because if Fiddler could have been opened you would have the same problem. My code, had nothing to do with fiddler intercepting the http request. REST is different in mny ways to a simple url browsing because its API is bounded to the HTTP protocol much stricter than what a browser does with only GET/POST commands