# why was the question on dev server setup moved to SU?

Tags: discussion

Coming from question:

- [How do I get Windows XP Professional upgrade to boot directly without having to choose it at startup?](https://serverfault.com/questions/173395/how-do-i-get-windows-xp-professional-upgrade-to-boot-directly-without-having-to-c?noredirect=1)

Why doesn't this question belong to SF?

It seems to fall into 2 categories of SF:

- Developers who need support getting their development environment up
- Beginner System Administrators and Students

according to [Perception of purpose](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/465/perception-of-purpose)

Answer (score 8):

> - Developers who need support getting their development environment up
> - Beginner System Administrators and Students

**Neither** of these are correct Server Fault categories. [From the FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq):

> Server Fault is for system
>   administrators and IT professionals,
>   people who manage or maintain
>   computers in a professional capacity

Therefore, anything that falls into those two categories does not belong on Server Fault. Sometimes we let it slide if the problem is a complex problem that just happens to be happening to a beginner/developer, but 99% of the time questions are shifted to their more appropriate site.

Comment: Dude is trolling. Leave him be.

Comment: Not a very good troll then

Comment: I am IT professional with 25 yrs of exp who manage and maintain computers in professional capacity

Comment: coming from your hijacking comments in http://serverfault.com/questions/174196/workgroup-windows-users-or-groups-can-use-domain-accounts-but-not-vice-versa. How did you determine that I did not read up before posting? Give me your Email and I send you my online transcripts and credentials