# Why is a closed question not closed?

Tags: discussion

Would it be possible to have a closed question really closed rather than sort of, kinda, nearly, half closed?

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/174196/workgroup-windows-users-or-groups-can-use-domain-accounts-but-not-vice-versa) is currently listed as having been closed 10 hours ago, yet was edited only 3 hours ago. Am I a fool for thinking that when a question is closed it should no longer be possible to post answers or comments and most importantly, not be editable? What have I missed, or does "closed" mean something different in other places?

Comment: See [What is a “closed” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

Comment: As @Zoredache states in his answer locking or deleting would be the way to go.  I think this particular question is beyond locking.  It's a big enough mess that I'd vote to completely torch it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignore vgv8 who is a bit of an unusual user of the system.

Lets imagine some typical user asks a question and it is vague or poorly worded and gets closed.  The system allows them to re-edit the question.  Then people can vote to re-open.  For a typical user fixing an existing question is generally better then reposting a new re-worded question.

Unfortunately vgv8 adds comments and edits questions far more then is typical or reasonable.  If it gets really annoying we can flag any questions to be locked or deleted I guess.

Comment: OK, in the context of any other user I suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I guess closed just means closed to new answers. Nice to see that our favourite user STILL doesn't understand how the site works after a week-long ban and plenty of discussions on meta.

Comment: Some people can be taught. Others can learn on their own. This one absolutely excels at being neither. :(

Comment: @John - he's still at it: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/742/why-was-the-question-on-dev-server-setup-moved-to-su/743#743