# Why is my question being voted down/deleted?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if anyone knew why the following question was being voted down:

https://serverfault.com/questions/435693/connect-to-my-virtualbox-mysql-server

I mainly use stack overflow but thought this question would be better here, was I wrong or have I not included enough info?

The question has been closed now and I have been pointed to the faq but it seems to me that the question is about hardware, software and virtualization as stated in that faq, am I misunderstanding the terminology?

Comment: Whether it's SF or any other site, please read *all* the FAQ, not just the little bit that when read in isolation appears to make your question valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important portion of the FAQ is the first line:

> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems **in a professional capacity**.

For more clarifying information relating to 'professional capacity', see this M.SF question:

["Server Fault is for system administrators... in a professional capacity"](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1760/server-fault-is-for-system-administrators-in-a-professional-capacity)

Linked from this [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)-tagged question, is another question which seems relevant here:

[why was the question on dev server setup moved to SU?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/742/why-was-the-question-on-dev-server-setup-moved-to-su)

It was determined very early on in SF's life that dev-server setup/maintenance/whatnot was Off Topic, which was soon expanded to include home-servers (which are often dev-servers too).

What distinguishes SF from our similarly scoped brethren (Unix & Linux, Ask Ubuntu, DBA, and of course Super User) is that we're about problems that come up *in the workplace during the normal execution of our paid-for-doing-this duties*. This is not an immediately obvious division of scope, which is why we put it in the very first line of the faq, **in bold letters**.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I guess my fault for not reading properly, I'll try over at SU

Answer (score 1):

If you hover your mouse over the down arrow, you'll see:

> This question does not show any any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Doesn't always apply yo why a question got downvoted, but in this case, that describes your question perfectly.  Unclear, seems to be something you'd know if you read the documentation, and least from the limited and unclear information provided, looks off-topic too.